# SplitterLocation doesn't save in the settings

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

i have created a splitterLocation setting, Type system.Drawing.Point and Scope : User. to save the splitter location when the user change it. and load again with the new location when the form load.

```
private void splitter1_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      MailSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.splitterLocation = splitter1.Location;
        MailSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        splitter1.Location = MailSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.splitterLocation;
     }
```

but it doesnt work i dont know why ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the saving code to the FormClosing event.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MailSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.splitterLocation = splitter1.Location;
  MailSystem.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

and make sure your splitter1 control isn't being docked, DockStyle.None.

Comment: yea the problem is that it's docked. Thank you